# PgfPlot - Style

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot numerical values stored in a file called `test1.dat`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title = ,
xlabel = {X},
ylabel= {Y},
scale only axis,
]
\addplot+ [blue] table {test1.dat};
\addlegendentry{Values}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am trying to print to have a plot similar the image below in terms the used `grid`, I don't know how to make the legend outside of the plot and finally the exact values should printed on the plot like (7.073, etc.).

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Bests,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `nodes near coords` is designed to add text near plot points, and by default it adds the y-value above the points. I added that option to the `axis`, which turns on the feature for all the plots. For the individual plots I specified how those nodes should be positioned (in the example, 10pt above/below the point itself), by using e.g. `nodes near coords align={above=10pt}`.
- `ymajorgrids` turns on the horizontal grid lines only. Add this to the `axis` options.
- The position of the legend is set with `legend style`, see code below, which has some comments.
- Perhaps you also want `axis lines*=left`.

(I don't of course have your data file, so I plotted a pair of linear functions.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title = ,
xlabel = {X},
ylabel= {Y},
scale only axis,
ymajorgrids, %  turn on horizontal grid lines
nodes near coords, % <-- adds y-values next to points
legend columns=-1, % legend entries distributed horizontally instead of vertically
legend style={
  at={(0.5,1)}, % coordinates are relative to axis box, (0,0) in bottom left, (1,1) in top right
  above, % place it above that coord
  draw=none % remove frame of legend
  },
samples=10 % just for example
]
\addplot+ [nodes near coords align={above=10pt}]  {x};
\addplot+ [nodes near coords align={below=10pt}]  {x-1};
\addlegendentry{Values}
\addlegendentry{Stuff}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```